# Instantiate a class from a list of classes given its name as a string

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a set of classes, where one class is the parent of several others.

```py
class Parent: pass
class Child1(Parent): pass
class Child2(Parent): pass
class Child3(Parent): pass
class Child4(Parent): pass
class Child5(Parent): pass
```

Given that I have a string that contains the name of one of the child classes, how can I instantiate that class?

I would expect something like the following to work:

```py
classname = "Child1"
child = Parent.__subclasses__()[classname]()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Please provide a usecase and maybe we can help you more.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I have an XML schema and a separate class for each possible XML node type. I would like to take the text of the XML node, format it into the class name for that node, and then instantiate that class as I'm traversing the XML tree.

Answer (score 0):

```py
classname = "Child1"
child = [cls for cls in Parent.__sublcasses()
         if cls.__name__ == classname][0]()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.